# MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND error in Redemption.dll library

Tags: c#, outlook, ms-office, mapi, outlook-redemption

I'm using Redemption.dll ( http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm ) in a project. The application uses MAPI to send emails for some testings. If the application is running on a machine that has outlook installed, it works fine.

However, if the outlook is not installed, I get this error when sending emails:

```
Error in IMsgServiceAdmin::CreateMsgService: MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND
```

After some search, I installed CDO 1.2.1 ( https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1004 ) on the machine, but still get the same error.

Does it mean that the outlook has to be installed on this machine? Or, has to figure out a way to create a MAPI profile on this machine wothout installing outlook?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you connecting to an Exchange mailbox or opening a PST file? Make sure there is only once instance of mapisvc.inf on your machine that lists the right MPAI services.

Comment: try to connect to Exchange mailbox. Say, on this machine, I installed CDO 1.2.1, what else I need to configure (without installing outlook)? Any doc explains this? thanks.

Comment: What version of Exchange are you hitting? Keep in mind that Exchange 2016 will explicitly refuse a connection coming from the standalone version of MAPI/CDO.

Comment: Ex2013. However, I hope it can also work for Ex2016. Maybe has to install outlook instead of having standardalone MAPI/CDO?

Comment: Yes, you can still install Outlook 2010 SP3, 2013 SP1 or 2016.

Comment: just want to make sure. You mean have to install outlook to make it work?

Comment: Yes, you can have Outlook installed on the server (for its MAPI system), you just can't se Outlook Object Model programmatically in service.